# What technological advance would allow LEP3 to surpass LEP2?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, accelerator-physics

I learned that for electron accelerators synchrotron radiation and acceleration are the limiting factors.

[This article](http://physicsworld.com/cws/article/news/2012/aug/06/physicists-unveil-plans-for-lep3-collider-at-cern), that I found in one answer to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/114048/what-were-the-maximal-collision-energy-of-the-lhc-if-it-were-rewired-to-e-e) mentions that one would **not** use the superconducting acceleration elements that were developed in the meanwhile, but rely on regular normal-conduction acceleration.

Then I wonder, at the same radius, what technological advance would allow LEP3 to surpass LEP2 in a significant ammount?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing really surprising here. The limit is basically how much energy you can add to the beam in the *space* left after you have installed all your bending and tuning magnets.

Both magnets and cavities are better now than they were then. More over, the size of both items has gotten slightly smaller allowing more of them to be packed into the same distance.