# What happens when an electron collides with an atomic nucleus?

Tags: electrons, collision, subatomic

Say an electron is shot towards an atom at such a speed that a violent collision (or just a regular collision) is unavoidable, what happens to electron and the nucleus?

(Also, I'm a mere highschooler. I don't really understand a lot about physics.)

Comment: Is the nucleus bare, or surrounded by an electron cloud?

Comment: This question is definitely rather broad (e.g., a question that requires a book for an answer) and is perhaps is a duplicate of [What would happen if Large Hadron Collider would collide electrons?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/53558/what-would-happen-if-large-hadron-collider-would-collide-electrons)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What would happen if Large Hadron Collider would collide electrons?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/53558/what-would-happen-if-large-hadron-collider-would-collide-electrons)

Comment: Not a duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/53558/what-would-happen-if-large-hadron-collider-would-collide-electrons as those answers refer to electron-positron or electron-electron colliders.

Comment: It depends on the collision energy and on the internal random generator of the Nature. A lot of things can happen. The problem is that detailing all of them would be a very long answer. Giving a short summary wouldn't be exact. It seems the community is now hesiting to close your question or not.

Comment: probably_someone, say it's Helium-4 with two electrons. What would be the difference?